# How to set X values as string

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have this code:

```
        data: {
            x : 'x',
            columns: [
                ['x', '30.03', '31.03', '01.04', '02.04', '03.04', '04.04', '05.04'],
                ['Ilość wejść', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
            ],
```

and it looks that:

[image: CLICK TO CHECK IMAGE]

The problem is here:

```
 ['x', '30.03', '31.03', '01.04', '02.04', '03.04', '04.04', '05.04'],
```

How I can make that this values will be accept as string, not as date format?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were aiming to get something like this:

[image]

I have never used this library, but I made some research on their website
& coded the following:

```
var chart2 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart2',
    data: {
      columns: [
      ['x', '30.03', '31.03', '01.04', '02.04', '03.04', '04.04', '05.04'],
        ['Ilość wejść', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
      ],
      axes: {
        data2: 'y2'
      },
      types: {
        'Ilość wejść': 'bar'
      }
    },
    axis: {
      y: {
        label: {
          text: 'Y Label',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      },
      y2: {
        show: true,
        label: {
          text: 'Y2 Label',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      }
    }
});
```

C3 WEBSITE: https://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html#generate

I would like to recommend chart.js, i think it is easier to use, better documentation & more people use it.

https://www.chartjs.org/

Using chart.js i got this result :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Line Styles</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

 <style>
 canvas{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div style="width:75%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
 <script>

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')

var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Bar Dataset',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        }, {
            label: 'Line Dataset',
            data: [30.03, 31.03, 1.04, 2.04, 3.04, 4.04, 5.04],

            // Changes this dataset to become a line
            type: 'line'
        }],
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7']
    },
});
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```